# Spring MVC - Apache CXF: Is there a main() or init() where I can spawn a worker thread on startup?

Tags: spring-mvc, cxf, jax-rs, maven-3

I am new to Apache CXF and Spring MVC. I would appreciate your help here.
I used Maven (mvn) to download the org.apache.cxf.archetype:cxf-jaxrs-service archetype (Simple CXF JAX-RS webapp service using Spring configuration). 
Here are the relevant artefacts and versions in pom.xml:

```
<properties>
    <jackson.version>1.8.6</jackson.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-rs-client</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

The web service works great. However, I need to spawn a thread on start-up to initialize a process that I would like to run on my web server. Normally I would do so in the main() method of a simple Java application or HttpServlet init().
Can you tell me how I could achieve the same here? This is a simple application, so I would prefer not to use an application server (e.g. JBOSS), Apache Camel, RMI, etc.

web.xml:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>WEB-INF/beans.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
    <listener-class>
                    org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
            </listener-class>
</listener>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>CXFServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
                    org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet
            </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>CXFServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to implement a custom ServletContextListener and do your work in the "contextInitialized" method.

https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html

You register it in your web.xml using the listener-class element.  You'll notice that Spring actually bootstraps itself in the same manner using its ContextLoaderListener.